# IP address for SMTP transport in Swiftmailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, ip

I have a server with one network interface with two IPs. How can I set exactly one IP to be used for SMTP transport?  I am using php library Swiftmailer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$transport->setLocalDomain('[127.0.0.1]');
```